# Creating a hook to a frequently accessed object

Tags: python

I have an application which relies heavily on a `Context` instance that serves as the access point to the context in which a given calculation is performed.

If I want to provide access to the `Context` instance, I can:

1. rely on `global`
2. pass the `Context` as a parameter to all the functions that require it

I would rather not use `global` variables, and passing the `Context` instance to all the functions is cumbersome and verbose.

How would you "hide, but make accessible" the calculation `Context`?

For example, imagine that `Context` simply computes the state (position and velocity) of planets according to different data.

```
class Context(object):
 def state(self, planet, epoch):
  """base class --- suppose `state` is meant
     to return a tuple of vectors."""
  raise NotImplementedError("provide an implementation!")

class DE405Context(Context):
"""Concrete context using DE405 planetary ephemeris"""
 def state(self, planet, epoch):
   """suppose that de405 reader exists and can provide
      the required (position, velocity) tuple."""
   return de405reader(planet, epoch)

def angular_momentum(planet, epoch, context):
 """suppose we care about the angular momentum of the planet,
    and that `cross` exists"""
 r, v = context.state(planet, epoch)
 return cross(r, v)

# a second alternative, a "Calculator" class that contains the context
class Calculator(object):

 def __init__(self, context):
  self._ctx = context

 def angular_momentum(self, planet, epoch):
  r, v = self._ctx.state(planet, epoch)
  return cross(r, v)

# use as follows:
my_context = DE405Context()
now = now() # assume this function returns an epoch
# first case:
print angular_momentum("Saturn", now, my_context)
# second case:
calculator = Calculator(my_context)
print calculator.angular_momentum("Saturn", now)
```

Of course, I could add all the operations directly into "Context", but it does not feel right.

In real life, the `Context` not only computes positions of planets! It computes many more things, and it serves as the access point to a lot of data.

So, to make my question more succinct: how do you deal with objects which need to be accessed by many classes?

I am currently exploring: python's context manager, but without much luck. I also thought about dynamically adding a property "context" to all functions directly (functions are objects, so they can have an access point to arbitrary objects), i.e.:

```
def angular_momentum(self, planet, epoch):
 r, v = angular_momentum.ctx.state(planet, epoch)
 return cross(r, v)

# somewhere before calling anything...
import angular_momentum
angular_momentum.ctx = my_context
```

### edit

Something that would be great, is to create a "calculation context" with a `with` statement, for example:

```
 with my_context:
  h = angular_momentum("Earth", now)
```

Of course, I can already do that if I simply write:

```
 with my_context as ctx:
  h = angular_momentum("Earth", now, ctx) # first implementation above
```

Maybe a variation of this with the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)?

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to create a class that stores the context as an attribute, or make the context a class that has attributes referencing other objects for the different things it does.  Why does it "not feel right" to make the calculations be attributes of the context?  What does the "context" actually represent?

Comment: Also, it sounds like you want the `Context` to be just like a global in every way, except not be a global. The problem with globals isn't that they're stored in `globals()`, it's that there's a single instance at global level that everyone implicitly shares. Any solution you come up with for a single instance at global level that everyone implicitly shares will the exact same downsides as a real global—except possibly for tricking a linter tool or a coworker. If that's the behavior you really want, make it a global.

Comment: @BrenBarn: The context represents a given implementation of data and algorithms. I tried creating a class that stores the context, but then I have to refer to this class everywhere, or provide hooks to all operations from that class (similar to "Calculator")... maybe I'll do that, but I want to see how others deal with this issue. Thanks!

Comment: @abarnert: it is "almost" global, except that I may use more than one context in a given "run" (certain portions of calculations, for example, use a "lower-fidelity" context, whereas others use "high-fidelity" context, but both calculations are used in a given run.

Comment: @Arrieta: I guess what I'm saying is, if all the operations are inherently dependent on the context, it seems like it makes sense to make the context a class and have the operations be methods.  Then there would be no "everywhere" besides the context itself.

Comment: @BrenBarn: I'm affraid you are right, and I will have to create a "brain" which implements all operations with a given Context - it is not too bad, but I somewhat wanted something along the lines of a context manager "with my_context: {all operations see the context}" kind of thing.

Comment: @Arrieta: But do you use more than one context concurrently? If not, you can just replace the global, or do the naive version of the context manager (which just replaces the global on `__enter__` and restores it on `__exit__`). Also, why _doesn't_ it feel right to make your functions all methods of `Context`, or of some class like `Calculator` that owns a `Context` (which would be the "traditional OOP" solution any late-90s class would teach)? There are examples in the stdlib that do both of those, that feel perfectly normal.

Comment: @abarnert: Yes, currently I use more than one context in a given run (mostly fidelity issues)... the `brain` does not sound too bad now that I'm thinking more about it.

Comment: @Arrieta: By "concurrently" I mean "at the same time". In other words, if task A uses context A, then task B switches to context B, etc., that's no problem for a global—unless task A might run _in the middle of task B running_. Depending on how that can happen (task B might re-use task A a as subtask, or you might be running them in separate threads or greenlets, or…), there are different solutions. But if that _can't_ happen, there's no problem to solve.

Comment: @abarnert: Yes in both cases; different contexts simultaneously, and concurrent access to a given context. The later is not implemented yet, but I do need to rely on it. I am not too concerned about locking because the operations are overwhelmingly read-only (except for a few poorly implemented calls which for some weird reason write "access logs" to the data structure and screw everything up while providing no benefit whatsoever).

Comment: @Arrieta: Well, concurrent access to a given context shouldn't be a problem, but using different contexts at the same time does mean you can't use a global. A thread-local is still a possibility, assuming there's a simple one-to-one correspondence between tasks and threads (that is, a thread doesn't run part of a task under one context, then switch to a different task in the middle). Otherwise, some kind of object membership or closure is the only real answer, and the OO pattern seems to make more sense here.

Answer (score 4):

You generally don't want to "hide" anything in Python. You may want to signal human readers that they should treat it as "private", but this really just means "you should be able to understand my API even if you ignore this object", not "you can't access this".

The idiomatic way to do that in Python is to prefix it with an underscore—and, if your module might ever be used with `from foo import *`, add an explicit `__all__` global that lists all the public exports. Again, neither of these will actually prevent anyone from seeing your variable, or even accessing it from outside after `import foo`.

See [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#global-variable-names) on Global Variable Names for more details.

Some style guides suggest special prefixes, all-caps-names, or other special distinguishing marks for globals, but PEP 8 specifically says that the conventions are the same, except for the `__all__` and/or leading underscore.

Meanwhile, the behavior you want is clearly that of a global variable—a single object that everyone implicitly shares and references. Trying to disguise it as anything other than what it is will do you no good, except possibly for passing a `lint` check or a code review that you shouldn't have passed. All of the problems with global variables come from being a single object that everyone implicitly shares and references, not from being directly in the `globals()` dictionary or anything like that, so any decent fake global is just as bad as a real global. If that truly is the behavior you want, make it a global variable.

Putting it together:

```
# do not include _context here
__all__ = ['Context', 'DE405Context', 'Calculator', …

_context = Context()
```

Also, of course, you may want to call it something like `_global_context` or even `_private_global_context`, instead of just `_context`.

But keep in mind that globals are still members of a module, not of the entire universe, so even a public `context` will still be scoped as `foo.context` when client code does an `import foo`. And this may be exactly what you want. If you want a way for client scripts to import your module and then control its behavior, maybe `foo.context = foo.Context(…)` is exactly the right way. Of course this won't work in multithreaded (or gevent/coroutine/etc.) code, and it's inappropriate in various other cases, but if that's not an issue, in some cases, this is fine.

Since you brought up multithreading in your comments: In the simple style of multithreading where you have long-running jobs, the global style actually works perfectly fine, with a trivial change—replace the global `Context` with a global [`threading.local`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) instance that contains a `Context`. Even in the style where you have small jobs handled by a thread pool, it's not much more complicated. You attach a context to each job, and then when a worker pulls a job off the queue, it sets the thread-local context to that job's context.

However, I'm not sure multithreading is going to be a good fit for your app anyway. Multithreading is great in Python when your tasks occasionally have to block for IO and you want to be able to do that without stopping other tasks—but, thanks to the GIL, it's nearly useless for parallelizing CPU work, and it sounds like that's what you're looking for. Multiprocessing (whether via the `multiprocessing` module or otherwise) may be more of what you're after. And with separate processes, keeping separate contexts is even simpler. (Or, you can write thread-based code and switch it to multiprocessing, leaving the `threading.local` variables as-is and only changing the way you spawn new tasks, and everything still works just fine.)

It may make sense to provide a "context" in the context manager sense, as an external version of the standard library's [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module did, so someone can write:

```
with foo.Context(…):
    # do stuff under custom context
# back to default context
```

However, nobody could really think of a good use case for that (especially since, at least in the naive implementation, it doesn't actually solve the threading/etc. problem), so it wasn't added to the standard library, and you may not need it either.

If you want to do this, it's pretty trivial. If you're using a private global, just add this to your `Context` class:

```
def __enter__(self):
    global _context
    self._stashedcontext = _context
    _context = self
def __exit__(self, *args):
    global context
    _context = self._stashedcontext
```

And it should be obvious how to adjust this to public, thread-local, etc. alternatives.

Another alternative is to make everything a member of the `Context` object. The top-level module functions then just delegate to the global context, which has a reasonable default value. This is exactly how the standard library [`random`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) module works—you can create a `random.Random()` and call `randrange` on it, or you can just call `random.randrange()`, which calls the same thing on a global default `random.Random()` object.

If creating a `Context` is too heavy to do at import time, especially if it might not get used (because nobody might ever call the global functions), you can use the singleton pattern to create it on first access. But that's rarely necessary. And when it's not, the code is trivial. For example, the [source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py) to `random`, starting at line 881, does this:

```
_inst = Random()
seed = _inst.seed
random = _inst.random
uniform = _inst.uniform
…
```

And that's all there is to it.

And finally, as you suggested, you could make everything a member of a different `Calculator` object which owns a `Context` object. This is the traditional OOP solution; overusing it tends to make Python feel like Java, but using it when it's appropriate is not a bad thing.

Comment: I think more than hiding it, is about making it easier to pass around. I don't want to make it necessarily or private. Instead, I want to make it easily replaceable everywhere without it being a global variable (hopefully).

Comment: I think either you _do_ want it to be global, or you want to make it like `random.Random()`, where everything in the module is a member of `Context`, but there is a global, and delegating functions, that can be used for simple cases where you don't need that complexity. If you explain why exactly you don't want a global, and what you do want that seems global-ish (or why you don't want to pass it around everywhere or use a class), it might help.

Comment: My beef with the globals is that if I need to use more than one context in a given run I'm out of luck. Also, if I could delegate the calls (as you suggest), I may be able to control access, which will be important when I port my code to the multi-threaded version (which I plan). Thanks.

Comment: @Arrieta: You're only out of luck if you need to use them concurrently. It doesn't sound like that's a problem today. If you switch to multithreading it will _become_ a problem, but there's a trivial solution using `threading.local`. (And I don't think you want multithreading anyway.) Edited again for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using a proxy object, here's a library that helps in creating object proxies:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ProxyTypes

Flask uses object proxies for it's "current_app", "request" and other variables, all it takes to reference them is:

```
from flask import request
```

You could create a proxy object that is a reference to your real context, and use thread locals to manage the instances (if that would work for you).

Comment: Thanks - I've been looking at how Flask implements its thread locals (it would also help me multithreading the code). I will look at the proxy class. Thanks!